# Symbolic link does not appear to exist

Tags: filesystems, osx, symlink

MacOS here, although I'm 99% sure this is a Unix question.

I'm trying to see exactly where MySQL is installed. In a terminal I enter:

```
which mysql
```

And I get:

```
/usr/local/bin/mysql
```

So I see what's in that directory (`ls -al /usr/local/bin/mysql`) which gives me:

```
lrwxr-xr-x  1 myuser  admin  32 Mar 20  2017 /usr/local/bin/mysql -> ../Cellar/mysql/5.7.17/bin/mysql
```

Ok. Symbolic link. So I try to go to that symbolic link via `ls -al ../Cellar/mysql/5.7.17/bin/mysql`) and I get:

```
ls: ../Cellar/mysql/5.7.17/bin/mysql: No such file or directory
```

**So where can I find `../Cellar/mysql/5.7.17/bin/mysql` on my machine?**

Comment: Could you check `/usr/local/Cellar`

Comment: or try `readlink -f /usr/local/bin/mysql`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The link is relative *to itself* (not whatever the current working directory of your process is) so lop off the `mysql` and add the remainder

```
/usr/local/bin/../Cellar/mysql/5.7.17/bin/mysql
```

or in other words

```
/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.7.17/bin/mysql
```

there's a `realpath(3)` system call that may or may not be exposed by the shell or programming language in question for resolving such without the manual work. Portability suffers on these various shell commands:

```
$ cd /var/tmp
$ touch file
$ ln -s ../tmp/file ourlink
$ realpath ourlink                      # because I'm in mksh, YMMV
/private/var/tmp/file
$ readlink ourlink
../tmp/file
$ readlink -f ourlink
readlink: illegal option -- f
usage: readlink [-n] [file ...]
$
```

You could also install the GNU coreutils and use those if you want a consistent external command interface to `realpath(3)` (with even more complications if you want GNU `readlink` to be called `readlink` and appear in `PATH` before the vendor-provided one).

```
$ greadlink ourlink
../tmp/file
$ greadlink -f ourlink
/private/var/tmp/file
$
```

Comment: Ah, the `..` was the giveaway!